# Compiling code on Jetson TK1

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, nvidia, tegra

I am compiling an application using the gcc arm cross compiler(arm-eabi-g++). I want to execute the code on the jetson tk1 target. When I copy the executable and run it on the target. I get an error saying `-bash: ./Proj: No such file or directory`

Should I include any extra conditions while building, inorder to run it on the target?

Can anyone suggest any other cross compiler that works?

Comment: You've presumably linked against libraries provided by the cross-toolchain, are those libraries also available on the target filesystem? Does it run OK if you link the executable statically?

Comment: The application i have written is a simple add program. It doesnt have any other libraries included. The executable compiles successfully on my host system. When I run it on the jetson tk1 target, i get the error mentioned. Since it is compiled for the arm target, i cannot run it on my host system(host is gcc based). I would like to know if any other build conditions are required for it to run on the target

Comment: That error looks like the file doesn't exist, or rather doesn't have executable permissions.

Answer (score 1):

It might be differing of system architecture and program architecture.

Look for the architecture of TX1 with command

```
uname -p
```

From JetPack v2.2 Jetson TX1 can be installed with aarch64 or armhf architecture

Simpliest way to cross compile is to use arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ for armhf and aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ for aarch64. You can run armhf  programs on aarch64 but you need to install armhf versions of all necessary libraries like libc or libstdc++:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev:armhf
```